# How can I sort a list of images by image height? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, image, sorting, height, python-imaging-library

how can I sort a list of images by image height?
List for example:

```
list = ['img1.png', 'img2.png','img3.png']

The height of img1 is 150
The height of img2 is 75
The height of img3 is 329
```

The expected result:

```
list = ['img3.png','img1.png','img2.png']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these images 2D arrays of digits?

Comment: @LapisRose Yeah

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi! Actually a few days after I asked this question, I succeeded to solve it in a complicated way. But I am pretty sure your answer is working. I cannot test it right now.But I will test later. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them by using the built in function "sorted" and sorting by the length of the array, which should sort by number of rows (height). Passing in True for the reverse keyword will let you sort in descending order.

```
list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But it's still sorting image but not by height, do you know why?

Comment: What datatype are your images? Could you post more of your code so I can give a better assesment?

Comment: Actually I got along. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of images and sort by height like this:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

# Generate a list of PNG files
filenames = glob.glob("*.png")

# Sort that list by height of image
byHeight = sorted(filenames, key=lambda x: Image.open(x).height)
```